# Port forwarding through 2 routers to client

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I have such a scheme

```
internet
|
router#1
static ip "ABC"
forward all ports to 192.168.1.10
|
router#2
wan IP = 192.168.1.10
lan ip = 192.168.2.1
inner dhcp 192.168.2.2 -- 192.168.2.245
forward port 200 to 192.168.2.200 local port 200
|
device (web cam)
ip = 192.168.2.200
port = 200
```

As I understand when user try to reach ABC:200 from internet the route should be:

```
ABC:200 --> 192.168.1.1:200 --> 192.168.1.10:200 --> 192.168.2.200:200
```

But the target host (192.168.2.200:200) is unreachable from internet.
Also if I connect to router#1 I can't ping 192.168.1.10, when reconnect to router#2 internet available and device is reachable.

Seems like there is lack of static route between 2 networks (1.0 and 2.0) but I can't understand the right way where and which route to add to let router#2 with wan 192.168.1.10 be reachable from router#1.

**UPDATED**

Now the current availability:

```
connect to router#1
192.168.1.10:200 --> 192.168.2.200:200 works fine.
```

All port forwarded from router#1 to 192.168.1.10 so I believe that route should be

```
inetaddr:200 --> 192.168.1.10:200 --> 192.168.2.200:200
```

But `inetaddr:200` not respond and,

```
inetaddr:8080(to router#2 web admin panel) respond
```

so seems like can't get access throught router#2 to device.

BUT if use 2 routers in 1 network (lan -- lan instead of lan -- wan) it works, so all ports on router#1 works fine.

Can't understand why router#2 is not accessable from internet.

Comment: You've pointed out (part) of your problem. Router #1 can't reach router #2, right? Then how can anything else work?

Comment: Which kind of router you are using? Sounds like there is a firewall running on router #2, blocking all incoming requests on wan port...

Comment: Not being able to ping the router doesn't tell you much on its own. Many devices are misguidedly configured not to answer ping, thinking that would make them invisible to attackers, (It doesn't.) I'd recomend to divide the problem space by connecting a PC to the 192.168.1.* network and check if you can reach (a) the Internet and (b) the webcam on 192.168.1.10:200 from it.

Comment: current router is asus AC68U. Router #1 can reach router #2 now but #2 still not accessable from internet. Could you check updates?

Comment: Is your webcam getting its address via dhcp or static configuration? If the former, are you sure it is .200? If the latter, check that the webcam has 192.168.2.1 as its default route. If you these aren't the problem, can you try port forwarding to a pc in the 192.168.2.0 network, where you have better diagnostics, e.g. a sniffer?

Comment: Yes, 2.200, it's a static ip and gateway for device is 2.1. I'm pretty sure that the deal is in some static routes, I can't get access only through the second router since second router is available via Internet